# What are the interpretations of 1 Sam 11:14 The renewal of Saul's kingship?

Tags: 1-samuel

> Then Samuel said to the people, "Come, let us go to Gilgal and there renew the kingship."

Is it just a description of the event or the book tries to say something about kingship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chapter earlier, Saul was declared king:

> 1 Samuel 10:23 They ran and brought him [Saul] out, and as he stood among the people he was a head taller than any of the others. 24Samuel said to all the people, “Do you see the man the Lord has chosen? There is no one like him among all the people.”
>
> Then the people shouted, “**Long live the king**!”
> ...
> 26 Saul also went to his home in Gibeah, accompanied by valiant men whose hearts God had touched. 27But some **scoundrels** said, “How can this fellow save us?” They despised him and brought him no gifts. But Saul kept silent.

But not everybody agreed. Some murmured and disdained Saul.

Later, war broke out:

> 1 Samuel 11:11 The next day Saul separated his men into three divisions; during the last watch of the night they broke into the camp of the Ammonites and slaughtered them until the heat of the day. Those who survived were scattered, so that no two of them were left together.

Now  Saul had proved himself in carrying out successful warfare.

To cut down the murmur and dissent, Samuel called for celebration and renewal of the kingship

> 14 Then Samuel said to the people, “Come, let us go to Gilgal and there **renew** the kingship.” 15 So **all the people** went to Gilgal and made Saul king in the presence of the Lord. There they sacrificed fellowship offerings before the Lord, and Saul and all the Israelites held a great celebration.

Politically, it served to unify all the Israelites to accept Saul as king.